# Understanding the recurrence relation $f(n,k) = kf(n-1, k) + (n-k+1)f(n-1,k-1)$ for the Euler numbers $f(n,k)$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, eulerian-numbers

The Euler numbers $f(n,k)$ are given in *Generatingfunctionology* as the number of permutations of $[n]$ with exactly $k$ increasing runs (exercise 1.18.c). Its recurrence relation is
$$f(n,k) = kf(n-1, k) + (n-k+1)f(n-1,k-1)$$ but I don't understand why the second term is multiplied by $(n-k+1)$.

My reasoning is as follows: there are $n$ positions you could stick the $n$ in a permutation of $[n-1]$. Of these, when adding to $k$ positions (ends of the increasing sequences) we will still have $k$ increasing runs $n$, while in the remaining $n-k$ positions we will get one more increasing sequence. Thus $f(n-1,k-1)$ should be multiplied by $n-k$.

What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Your reasoning is basically sound, but you are making a fencepost error.  Consider a permutation of $[n-1]$ with exactly $k-1$ increasing runs.  There are $k-1$ places you could put the $n$ which would preserve the number of runs (namely, at the end of any of the $k-1$ runs).  If you put it in any of the other $n-(k-1)=n-k+1$ you add a run.

Comment: For what it is worth, there are $k-1$ positions, not $k$ positions, which preserve the number of increasing sequences, because $f(n-1,k-1)$ counts permutations with $k-1$ increasing sequences.

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks guys :)